# Does an inherited explicit templated variadic constructor affect the default-initializability of a type?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Should `d` be considered default-initializable according to the C++20 standard?

```cpp
#include <concepts>

struct b { explicit b(auto...) {} };
struct d : b {};
static_assert(std::default_initializable<d>); // clang nope, gcc ok, msvc nope
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GKKdYrav3)

---

Clang's error message:

```cpp
<source>:5:15: error: static assertion failed
    5 | static_assert(std::default_initializable<d>);
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:5:15: note: because 'd' does not satisfy 'default_initializable'
/gcc/include/concepts:160:6: note: because '_Tp{}' would be invalid:
chosen constructor is explicit in copy-initialization
  160 |         _Tp{};
      |             ^
```

MSVC's error message:

```cpp
<source>(5): error C2607: static assertion failed
<source>(5): note: the concept 'std::default_initializable<d>' evaluated to false
/msvc/include/concepts(100): note: 'd': no appropriate default constructor available
/msvc/include/concepts(100): note: Invalid aggregate initialization
/msvc/include/concepts(100): note: 'b': no appropriate default constructor available
/msvc/include/concepts(100): note: Constructor for struct 'b' is declared 'explicit'
```

Answer (score 3):

The constructor `b::b` is not inherited by `d`. `d`, which has no user-declared constructor, has a default constructor implicitly declared by the compiler according to [[class.default.ctor]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.default.ctor#1).

Now, `d`'s implicitly defined default constructor is perfectly usable. [[class.default.ctor]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.default.ctor#4) explains that it initializes bases and members as if it were a user-written constructor with the *ctor-initializer* omitted, and [[class.base.init]/9.3](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#9.3) states that this results in the default-initialization of the bases and members. This default-initialization is not a copy-initialization, so it can use the `explicit` constructor of `b`.

But Clang says that `d` doesn't satisfy the `std::default_initializable` concept and helpfully explains why. This concept requires not only that default-initialization of `d` is well-formed, but also that `d{}` is well-formed ([[concept.default.init]](https://eel.is/c++draft/concept.default.init)). Because `d` has no user-declared or inherited constructors, it satisfies the definition of an [aggregate](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#1), which means `d{}` invokes aggregate initialization ([[dcl.init.list]/3.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.4)).

Here's where the problem arises. In the aggregate initialization `d{}`, because there is no initializer supplied for the `b` subobject, the `b` subobject is implicitly copy-initialized from an empty initializer list ([[dcl.init.aggr]/5.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#5.2)). And since this is a copy-initialization, it is ill-formed for it to use the explicit constructor `b::b(auto...)`.

Why does GCC accept it? I don't know; some bug, I guess.